# is it possible to change URL of webpage using .htaccess and also want to protect folders using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I want to change Webpage URL http://www.xyz.com/in/index.php?mpid=page1 to http://www.xyz.com/in/page1 using .htaccess.

And also want to protect my folders with username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
#path to htpaswd
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^in
RewriteRule /in/(.+) in/index.php?mpid=$1
```